# Clicking button to send info in text box not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to make this: `static private long number = (long)Math.Floor(GlobalRandom.NextDouble * 9_000_000_000L) + 1_000_000_000L;`   to be returned with this:

```
public string MyValtwo
        {
            get { return myValtwo; }
            set { myValtwo = value; }
        }
```

and finally to be sent to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyValtwo = textBox2.Text;
        }
```

I tried converting: `public string MyValtwo = Convert.ToString(number);` but nothing returns or the long (number) can't be converted into string.

The main idea is to be generated a number and automatically putted in form 1 text box

Comment: will textBox2.Text contain the `long` number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need `MyValtwo`. Change code to below and it will work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = number.ToString();
}
```

In case you want to store the value of `number` as text in `MyValtwo` then you can add below line in `button1_Click` function.

```
MyValtwo = number.ToString();
```